# Delete a file inside subfolder using bat

Tags: command-line, batch, search, batch-file

I know the name of the subfolder inside which the file I want to delete is located. The name of the subfolder is "My Subfolder" and the file I want to delete inside the subfolder is "The-Bad File.txt" . I am at "D" drive. "My Subfolder" is located inside `D:\Folder-2\` ; `D:\Folder-4\`; `D:\Folder-54\`; `D:\Folder-543\`etc etc (I don't know the actual folder names inside which "My Subfolder" is). I want to search these folders only to delete "Bad File.txt" using .bat file.

I don't want this : -

```
@echo off
del /s "Bad File.txt"
```

This will search the entire drive, which will take time. What I want in more perfect word is, I want to search for "My Subfolder" First. Then Inside "My Subfolder" want to delete the "Bad File.txt"

Answer (score 2):

If you're ABSOLUTELY SURE there is only one instance of My Subfolder, then:

```
@echo off
Set StartFolder=D:\Path\To\A\Folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /s /b /ad "%StartFolder%"') Do del "%%a\Bad File.txt"
```

Just change the path for "StartFolder" on line two to the folder you want to start looking in.

Though I really don't think searching for the folder is going to improve the time it takes (not by much at least).

Comment: I think this is the answer I was looking for. Please do a bit more? The "Bad File.txt" is not inside `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\` in all the cases. Its can be in `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\xxxx\" or may be in `D:\Folder-x\My Subfolder\xxxx\yyyyy\" whatever the case is, "Bad File.txt" should be deleted. Please help; this answer is toooooo close..

Comment: The "/s" on the DIR command will find it anywhere under the top level from which you search.

Comment: I only want to make a search inside `D:\Folder-x` for `My Subfolder` It should not make a deep search.. Is there any way to search all the folders under D drive for My Subfolder but it will not make a deep search in all the folders of drive.. I.e, D:\Level1 Folder\ . But will not look into D:\Level1 Folder\Level2 Folder\ etc..

Comment: If i understand correctly... you want to search one level deep for the `My Subfolder` and delete all `Bad File.txt` from all its subfolders (deep search). You might want to use `for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('DIR /b /ad "%StartFolder%"') Do del /s "%%a\My Subfolder\Bad File.txt"`. Note the lack of `/s` in `DIR` and the addition of `/s` **and** `\My Subfolder\ ` in the `del`. The first `DIR` will only search the main-subfolders on `D:\ ` and the `del /s` will delete all `"Bad File.txt"` in `My Subfolder` and all its subfolders. If this is not what you want you might want to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the TCMD command-line, it's super easy:

```
global if exist "Bad File.txt" del "Bad File.txt"
```

This is WAY faster than `del /s`.  I'd estimate 100X for a hard drive with a few thousand folders.

You might want to use `global /q` if the screen drawing of each directory name slows things down. I know it does for me, because my card is driving 3 1080p displays.